# Multiple RPIs to 1 PC communication with CAN BUS

Tags: raspbian, ethernet, communication

I have to establish multiple RPI(Let's say 2-3) to 1 PC communication. I have to set up a CAN bus in either the PC or RPI. I am considering using an Ethernet cable and setting up a python server on the raspberry pi side, and a client on the windows side. Should I go for Ethernet or wifi or is there a better way to do it? I am completely new to RPI. My RPIs have Raspbian OS in it.
Thanks

Comment: Hi @Farhan Kabir，Welcome and nice to meet you. Ah, let me see, CAN, Ether, or WiFi, it all depends. It is a SAD problem: (1)    
"System Analysis and Design Tutorial for Absolute Newbies - Tutorials Point":
https://www.tutorialspoint.com/system_analysis_and_design/index.htm. Cheers

Comment: More newbie references if you wish to dig deeper: (2) "Systems Engineering - Wikpedia":
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Systems_engineering,

(3) "Engineering Systems Analysis for Design - MIT OCW Course":
https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/engineering-systems-division/esd-71-engineering-systems-analysis-for-design-fall-2008/,

(4) "System Analysis, Design, and Development Concepts, Principles, and Practices (eBook) - CS Wasson, Wiley 2006":
http://www.zu.edu.jo/UploadFile/Library/E_Books/Files/LibraryFile_12159_26.pdf. Cheers.

Comment: I am recommending the above eBook, because it is free. Of course you are not going to read if from cover to cover. Usually I just read the skim (not reading, actually) the preface, contents, and select one or two chapters, just to show off to my bad Arduino friends that I am a "system developer", and that I am developing "system integration" projects, unlike those amateurish Anono Micky Mouse toy projects. Now let us skim Part I System Analysis Concepts, Part II System Design and Development Practices
and jump to Chapter 55 System Integration, Test, and Evaluation.

Comment: You might like to start with summarizing your CAN experience before doing any requirement analysis. You might like to tell us your environment, say, eg, is it an auto shop already using CAN everywhere etc, ... WiFi is common and straightforward. On the other hand, CAN can be very tricky, but its hardware cost is falling fast, even amateurish guys are talking about it so perhaps it is time to do a feasibility study.

Comment: At the end of day, you still need to make engineering trade offs and cost benefit analysis. Before that, you need to read technical papers comparing things, such as ***RS232 vs CAN, WiFi vs BLE etc***. The following Silicon Labs wired and wireless connect white paper is a good one: guide:https://www.silabs.com/whitepapers/connect-your-mcu. Cheers.

Comment: that seems like a lot of reading. Does this book specifically talk about raspberry pi?

Comment: Ah, I did not read the 800 pages book cover to cover.  I just skimmed the preface, and then jumped to Chapter 55. And finally read the SLab's white paper. Now I am a fake expert.